# Robocopy move won't start

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have the following script that I'm using to move all files older than 30 days to a backup folder (I know there are files that meet this criteria...however when I run the script I get the following screen, and nothing actually happens.

```
 @ECHO OFF

 ROBOCOPY "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SHAPISIP\logs" "D:\SHAPISIP LOGS" *.log* /move /minage:30

 EXIT
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What output do you get by including the **`/L`** and possibly even the **`/V`** logging options?

Comment: it spits out a string of files that aren't even in the source directory and then quits.

Comment: Try just running it directly in a command window so that you can read, and possibly post, the output. Also make sure you run `robocopy.exe` or better still `"%__APPDIR__%robocopy.exe"` just to ensure that the correct executable is being run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't patient enough. There were a significant amount of files in this directory and it just took a while to get going. It looked like it was doing nothing but it was.